# Delphi XE8 Indy OpenSSL , after update for windows 11 i got error 14077410 SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO

Tags: delphi, openssl, indy, handshake

I have a project that still works on Windows 10, and it was working on Windows 11.  But, after I installed updates for Windows 11 (not 22H2):

[image]

I now get an error:

> error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert
> handshake failure.

My setup is Indy 10.6.2.5263, OpenSSL 1.0.2u, Delphi XE8, and I am using the following code:

```
CInitialized := false;
idHttpC := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
idHttpC.ConnectTimeout := 80000;
idHttpC.ReadTimeout := 80000;
idHttpC.AllowCookies := true;

// config Redirect's
idHttpC.RedirectMaximum := 35;
idHttpC.HandleRedirects := true;
idHttpC.HTTPOptions := [hoTreat302Like303, hoKeepOrigProtocol];
idHttpC.OnRedirect := IdHTTP1Redirect;

// create Cookie's
idCookieC := TIdCookieManager.Create(IdHttpC);
idHttpC.CookieManager := idCookieC;

// create gzip Compressor
idHttpC.Compressor := TIdCompressorZLib.Create(idHttpC);

// create OpenSSL
lIOHandlerC := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(nil);
lIOHandlerC.SSLOptions.Mode := sslmClient;
lIOHandlerC.SSLOptions.SSLVersions := [sslvTLSv1, sslvTLSv1_1, sslvTLSv1_2];
idHttpC.IOHandler := lIOHandlerC;
```

On my request:

```
Result := idHttpC.Get('https://leinestern.de/');
```

I get:

> error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure.

What's is wrong here? Maybe I have to change some *new* settings?

I am not using any antivirus or firewall, the built-in antivirus and firewall are disabled.

Comment: now i see that i got another update on 21.09.2022 and it is "Servicing Stack 10.0.22000.1035" or KB5017383. Unfortunately it's not possible to uninstall.

Comment: Are you using the Indy that shipped pre-installed with XE8? If so, that version (from 2015) predates Indy's support for client-side SNI in the TLS handshake (added in 2016), which nowadays many websites require. You will likely have to upgrade your Indy to the latest version from its [GitHub repo](https://github.com/IndySockets/Indy/), see [Updating Indy](https://github.com/IndySockets/Indy/wiki/Updating-Indy) for instructions.

Comment: @RemyLebeau no, i update it from github, not this year, but it was working even on win11 before KB5017383 update, Unfortunately it's not possible to uninstall. more information on KB5017811

Comment: Without seeing the actual TLS handshake, I can't really help you with OpenSSL failures. And I have no clue how Windows updates affect OpenSSL. You may need to ask the OpenSSL community for help. Of course, they are likely to tell you to stop using 1.0.2u and update to 1.1.x or 3.x instead. But `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL` does not support those versions, you would have to use [this work-in-progress SSLIOHander](https://github.com/IndySockets/Indy/pull/299) instead for that.

Comment: @RemyLebeau today i updated indy from GitHub and its work again. Anyway i think the new windows update have some changes in TLS.

Comment: OpenSSL implements TLS on its own, it does not rely on Windows' implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i updated Indy from GitHub and it's working again.

Comment: This is not an answer. And you surely meant "it's _working_ again" (noun versus verb).