# Delphi TRestRequest TLS problem with Windows KB5018410 update

Tags: rest, delphi

With KB5018410 Windows update installed in Windows 10 recently, my Delphi REST applications have stopped working. It seems that TLS 1.2 is turned off. Insomnia, Firefox etc can access the URL below, but not a "default" set of `TRESTClint`/`TRESTRequest`/`TRESTResponse` components dropped on a form with the minimal required Properties modifications.

https://yams.ked.co.za/version

Checking boxes under `TRESTClient.SecureProtocols` also does not seem to make any difference.

How can I get my (very large) REST application going again!?

Comment: I was just reading about something similar earlier today, but it's related to KB5017380 instead: [Windows 10: Beware of a possible TLS disaster on October 2022 patchday](https://borncity.com/win/2022/10/11/windows-10-achtung-vor-einem-mglichen-tls-desaster-zum-oktober-2022-patchday/).

Comment: Strong suspicions that there are problems with the TREST components in Delphi. Many are seeing that updating to KB5018410 causes their software to work, and rolling back causes it to work again.

Comment: Correction : KB5018410 causes their software to **stop working**, and rolling back causes it to work again

Comment: i got same [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73935350/) with indy, did you try to update REST application?

Comment: @EvgenyLevitskiy your problem with Indy was not related to Windows TLS updates, you were simply using an outdated version of Indy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My final solution was to use another, 3rd party component (Chilkat) to carry out the REST functionality.

There is also the option of rolling back (and then blocking repeat upgrading) the Windows 10 KB5018410 upgrade.

The problem with the Embarcadero REST components was reported on the Issues site, and has now been elevated from "Reported" to "Open" status.

Answer (score 0):

Check this conversation out on Reddit - Global Protect TLS issue after install of KB5018410

https://www.reddit.com/r/paloaltonetworks/comments/y21chi/some_of_our_users_are_having_issues_connecting_to/

Comment: Yes, I've checked that, but it's unfortunately not a help. There's also a thread going at https://en.delphipraxis.net/topic/7628-trestclient-security-error-12175-following-windows-update/

It seems that an Embarcadero fix of the TRESTxxxx components is required.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Check your ssl cert and make sure your cert is not valid for more than 1 year 365 days. If it is issued to be longer than a year try switching your cert to one that is only good for 1 year and see if it solves it. That fixed my Palo Alto global protect vpn issue.